# Possible to launch Apple's default weather app from my application?

Tags: ios, ios4, feasibility

One of my client wants to open Apple's native weather app from our application. After few I don't see a possible way, unless we need to go with any 3rd party apps which provides custom url scheme.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899

It would be great if someone confirm or give me a lead if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible, the weather app doesn't have a known URL scheme and I dubt that it has an unknown one.

Comment: Not true anymore with iOS 16 and macOS Ventura. See my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76245636/265940

Answer (score 1):

The website **[handleOpenURL](http://handleopenurl.com/)** is an excellent resource for custom iOS URL schemes; [use this link](http://handleopenurl.com/search?scheme=apple) to search for the known Apple app schemes.

Unfortunately the weather app is not among them.

---

Another couple of sites with schemes (handleOpenURL seems to be the most complete, but it can't hurt to check the others):

**[app lookup](http://applookup.com/)**

**[Akosma iPhone URL Scheme Wiki](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)**

Comment: applookup.com seems down.

Answer (score 1):

At least with iOS 16.4 on device and in macOS Ventura you can open a URL like the following and it will act as a Universal Link and open the native Weather app showing weather close the given coordinate.

https://weather.apple.com/?lat=50.237&long=-122.022

I discovered this URL by using the Maps app on the simulator and long pressing the weather badge.  This brings up a larger weather panel and if you tap that Maps.app tries to open the URL but fails on the simulator.

Comment: Currently for that link to work on the web it seems like a city is required. Like this: https://weather.apple.com/?city=Boston&lat=42.3226734&lng=-71.0924375

Answer (score 0):

You can open the weather app with this URL: weather://

Here is a codepen demo I got to work: https://codepen.io/irom1/pen/KKeZBMW

```html
<a href="weather://" target="_blank">Open weather</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is searching for an answer: weather://weather.apple.com/?lat=37.323&long=-122.03218 did it for me. This way you can link to a specific location.

Comment: You can use https instead of weather: on the current iOS and macOS versions as the app supports Universal Links now.

Comment: Any idea how to open it to a search location based on a string instead of lat/long?