# how to call existing yahoo weather and calculator in an app

Tags: ios

I have a view that enables the user to access calculator and weather information. Once i click on weather, it should go to the existing weather forecast. And when i click on calculator it should call the inbuilt calculator application in iphone.

For this i want to call the inbuilt yahoo weather forecast and calculator from that view. How can i do that??

Something like [this](http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/119/Purple2/v4/a3/a2/d1/a3a2d12c-5f01-5484-bdc0-55a923eeaca7/mzl.ojnxvyus.320x480-75.jpg).

Comment: This is currently not possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107039/possible-to-launch-apples-default-weather-app-from-my-application

Answer (score 0):

for the [Yahoo Weather App](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/yahoo!-weather/id628677149?mt=8) the URL scheme is the following:

```
yweather://
```

when you open this URL from your app, the Yahoo Weather application will be launched, if it is already installed on the actual device.

if it is not installed yet, you will get *invalid URL* error in your application. (I don't know the exact HTTP error code in the very moment.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use yahoo weather app because its been deprecated now. And I have     used worldweatheronline API to achieve this.

It's very easy to use and we can retrieve the weather report for n number(5,6 days or a    week).

http://www.worldweatheronline.com/

It may help others. Thanks for trying to help with your answers.